# Combine text files and delete duplicate lines

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line

How do I efficiently combine multiple text files and remove duplicate lines in the final file in Ubuntu?

I have these files:

file1.txt contains

```
alpha
beta
gamma
delta
```

file2.txt contains

```
beta
gamma
delta
epsilon
```

file3.txt contains

```
delta
epsilon
zeta
eta
```

I would like the final.txt file to contain:

```
alpha
beta
gamma
delta
epsilon
zeta
eta
```

I would appreciate the help.

Comment: Does the order of the lines in the  final file matter? Otherwise, `sort -u all the input files > output` would do it.

Comment: The order of lines doesn't matter.

The result of `sort -u file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt > final.txt` contains 2 of `delta` and 2 of `epsilon`. I was looking for something that matches the `final.txt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to print only the first instance of each line without sorting:

```
$ awk '!seen[$0]++' file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
alpha
beta
gamma
delta
epsilon
zeta
eta
```

Comment: The output for `awk '!seen[$0]++' file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt` contains 2 lines of `delta` and 2 lines of `epsilon`. I am looking to remove any additional duplicates.

Comment: @AvidLearner I tested it with the *exact* input you posted - if you are seeing something different, then your files are not the same (i.e. some apparently duplicate lines are actually distinct - for example, they have trailing whitespace)

Comment: Thank you. The trailing white spaces were the issue. I should have added my output of commands I tried in the original post for clarity.

Comment: @AvidLearner if the inputs consist of single words per line, then you can avoid the trailing whitespace issue by keying on `$1` rather than `$0`

Answer (score 5):

Very Simple

```
sort -u file[123].txt
```